# Por que meu procedure não está sendo aceito, estou usando mysql6.3

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

```
create procedure cadastrar_nadador (out nome_v varchar(80),out sexo_v varchar(1),out nascimento_v date,out patrocinio_v varchar(80))
    begin
        insert into nadador(nome,sexo,nascimento,patrocinio)
        values (nome_v,sexo_v,nascimento_v,patrocinio_v); 
    end;
```

Comment: o ideal seria voce mostrar o erro e a estrutura da tabela.

Comment: Coloque o Erro e a estrutura da sua tabela aqui.
Pessoas votam negativo mas não querem comentar aqui p/ ajudar ..

Answer (score 0):

Olá tenta utilizar a seguinte sintaxe como base para sua procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE nome_procedimento ()
BEGIN
    /*CORPO DO PROCEDIMENTO*/
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pois me parece um erro na sintaxe na verdade.